# ListView doesn't appear

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I'm pretty beginner,so take me easy .I try to show a listview and when i click on one item from this listview to appear as checked. Why the listview doesn't appear , and how i can 
fix this . Thank you !

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        CheckListActivity ck;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);             

        ck=new CheckListActivity();     

    }
```

CheckListActivity.java :

```
public class CheckListActivity  extends ListActivity{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    String[] presidents = {
            "Dwight D. Eisenhower",
            "John F. Kennedy",
            "Lyndon B. Johnson",
            "Richard Nixon",
            "Gerald Ford",
            "Jimmy Carter",
            "Ronald Reagan",
            "George H. W. Bush",
            "Bill Clinton",
            "George W. Bush",
            "Barack Obama"
            };

    ListView listview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //list_view_rows    
         listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listafisiere);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.list_view_rows, R.id.ListMea, presidents);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(parent, v, position, id);
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected " + presidents[position],
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: In your manifest file change .MainActivity to .CheckListActivity

Comment: Content View of MainActivity isn't content ListView with data, try to show MainActivity replace for MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need 2 activities to do that. Please try the following, it should be enough:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    String[] presidents = {
            "Dwight D. Eisenhower",
            "John F. Kennedy",
            "Lyndon B. Johnson",
            "Richard Nixon",
            "Gerald Ford",
            "Jimmy Carter",
            "Ronald Reagan",
            "George H. W. Bush",
            "Bill Clinton",
            "George W. Bush",
            "Barack Obama"
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.list_view_rows, R.id.ListMea, presidents);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected " + presidents[position],
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

To start one activity from another:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you ! In the future if i want to call that CheckListActivity in MainActivity how should i do ?

Comment: @user3411394 I've edited my post to show how to start one activity from another

Comment: It's work now! In the future if i want to call that CheckListActivity in MainActivity how should i do ? Example in one Activity to have multiples activity

Comment: @user3411394 please take a look here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to set adapter like this.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, presidents);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: First of all how are you creating listview in xml. Then assign adapter as this.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: main xml :   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listafisiere"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >
    </ListView>

Comment: listviewrows.xml :   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListMea"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Lista_mea"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />